# Sorting data in descending order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have made a flask app which runs my yolo model through a webcam. alongside the webcam ive created a CSV table which detects the objects and prints their object name, probability and timestamp. I want to print it in descending order so that everytime I run the script the last ran code(or rows) would be written in the first rows itself instead of scrolling down the table.

I tried to sort the values according to the timestamps but it doesn't work.

```py
x=[]

for i in l:
    x=i.split(" ")
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Object': [x[0]],'Probability': [x[1]], 'Timestamp': [datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")]})
    df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort')
    # df.groupby(.ORDER_DATE.dt.day)
    df.to_csv('objects.csv', mode = 'a', index = False, encoding = "utf8")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort')
```

or

```
df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort', inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either override the dataframe or add the `inplace` flag, according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

`df = df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort')` or `df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, inplace=True, kind='quicksort')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `inplace=True` for df.sort_values, otherwise the method would return a copy of the frame with rows sorted (like many other pandas methods do).

Answer (score 0):

The sort function returns a new, sorted DataFrame.
It doesn't overwrite the original one.
Therefor you just need:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort')
```